# Where can we use Variable Scoping and Shadowing in Go?

Tags: go, scope, lexical-scope, shadowing

Some related posts I've found:

- [go variable scope and shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458547/go-variable-scope-and-shadowing)
- [Golang: variable scope inside if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475153/golang-variable-scope-inside-if-statements)
- [Limit the scope of variables storing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531188/limit-the-scope-of-variables-storing-error/36533655)

Also there are many use cases to Variable Scoping and Shadowing.
Any code samples or answers will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not really sure about your purpose here, but maybe you can make a nice blogpost out of this.

Comment: just  interesting and informative to share, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Variable scoping and shadowing:**

> Go is lexically scoped using blocks:
>
> 1. The scope of a predeclared identifier is the universe block.
> 2. The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or
>      function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function)
>      is the package block.
> 3. The scope of the package name of an imported
>      package is the file block of the file containing the import
>      declaration.
> 4. The scope of an identifier denoting a method
>      receiver, function parameter, or result variable is the function body.
> 5. The scope of a constant or variable identifier declared inside a
>      function begins at the end of the ConstSpec or VarSpec (ShortVarDecl
>      for short variable declarations) and ends at the end of the innermost
>      containing block.
> 6. The scope of a type identifier declared inside a
>      function begins at the identifier in the TypeSpec and ends at the end
>      of the innermost containing block.
>      **An identifier declared in a block may be redeclared in an inner block.**
>      While the identifier of the inner declaration is in scope, it
>      denotes the entity declared by the inner declaration.
>
> The package clause is not a declaration; the package name does not
>   appear in any scope. Its purpose is to identify the files belonging to
>   the same package and to specify the default package name for import
>   declarations.

#### Advantages:

- Since data cannot be accessed from outer scope, Data Integrity is preserved

---

#### Different forms of Variable shadowing in Go:

1. Golang way to limit variable scope (using short-hand assignment inside statements):

   ```golang
   package main
   import "fmt"
   func main() {
       i := 10 //scope: main
       j := 4
       for i := 'a'; i < 'b'; i++ {
           // i shadowed inside this block
           fmt.Println(i, j) //97 4
       }
       fmt.Println(i, j) //10 4

       if i := "test"; len(i) == j {
           // i shadowed inside this block
           fmt.Println(i, j) // i= test , j= 4
       } else {
           // i shadowed inside this block
           fmt.Println(i, j) //test 40
       }
       fmt.Println(i, j) //10 4
   }
   ```
2. When "we need more alphabets", this is nice way to **limit variables scope**.
   Also this works well when you need more local variables or scope:

   **using `{` and `}` pair:**
   Pros: no need to extra statements like if, for, …

   ```golang
   package main
   import "fmt"
   func main() {
       i := 1
       j := 2
       //new scope :
       {
           i := "hi" //new local var
           j++
           fmt.Println(i, j) //hi 3
       }
       fmt.Println(i, j) //1 3
   }
   ```
3. Another way to limit variable scope is **using function calls**:
   Pros: scope limit, input value type parameters are usable like local variables,
   Cons: call/return time, and stack usage: if it is not optimized by compiler

   ```golang
   package main
   import "fmt"
   func fun(i int, j *int) {
       i++                //+nice: use as local var without side effect
       *j++               //+nice: intentionally use as global var
       fmt.Println(i, *j) //11 21
   }
   func main() {
       i := 10 //scope: main
       j := 20
       fun(i, &j)
       fmt.Println(i, j) //10 21
   }
   ```
4. Another way is **shadowing global variables**:

   ```golang
   package main
   import "fmt"
   var i int = 1 //global
   func main() {
       j := 2
       fmt.Println(i, j) //1 2
       i := 10           //Shadowing global var
       fmt.Println(i, j) //10 2
       fun(i, j)         //10 2
   }
   func fun(i, j int) {
       //i := 100        //error: no new variables on left side of :=
       //var i int = 100 //error: i redeclared in this block
       fmt.Println(i, j) //10 2
   }
   ```

See: [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) and [Scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).
And: [Declarations and scope](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope):