# Golang variable assignment

Tags: go

Is there a way in go to assign two variables to a function that returns two values when you have one variable declared and the other not.

For example:

```
var host string
if host, err := func(); err != nil {}
```

In the above code, host is declared but err isn't. I want a clean way to do this other than declaring err

Comment: Pretty sure it does that automatically. := if there is a new variable, = if both exist.

Comment: If the second statement is an if/for statement. Will the declared variable "host" hold the value returned by func()?

Comment: Short answer is what you're asking for isn't possible. You have to also declare `err`.

Comment: @Keeto see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553134/in-golang-where-can-we-use-variable-scoping-and-shadowing-and-how

Answer (score 7):

In your example you simply shouldn't be declaring host. There is no way to do partial assignment like that... Either your using `:=` which is short hand for declaration and assignment or you using `=` and you're doing assignment only. I personally very rarely write the word `var` in Go.

To be clear, if you have one variable that has already been declared with one or more that have not, you're allowed to use `:=` to assign to it, but the inverse is not true. Meaning you cannot use `=` if one or more of the left hand side values haven't been declared already.

Comment: If the second statement is an if/for statement. Will the declared variable "host" hold the value returned by func()?

Comment: @Keeto it will, however when you do that `host` will only be available in the scope of the `if`. Here's an example on play; https://play.golang.org/p/3ONeB2D6kH

As you can see host isn't in scope outside the if.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `:=` in an `if` like that, you will always get new variables declared in the scope of the `if`. Following the `if`, the value of `host` will be the same as it was before. If you want to do this, you need to declare both `host` and `err` before the `if` (and don't use `:=` in the `if`).